# I have a relatively simple ReactJSX application and I'm not sure why I'm getting a missing ";" on both Player move(dx, dy) and draw(context) error

Tags: reactjs

I have a relatively simple ReactJSX application and I'm not sure why I'm getting a missing ";" on move(dx, dy) and draw(context) error.

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactRogue from './ReactRougue'

const App = () => (
    <div className="App">
        <ReactRogue />
    </div>
)

export default App
```

ReactRogue.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Player from './Player'
import InputManager from './InputManager'

const ReactRougue = ({ width, height, tileSize }) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef()
    const [player, setPlayer] = useState(new Player(1, 2, tileSize))
    let InputManager = new InputManager()
    const handleInput = (action, data)
    let newPlayer = new Player()
    object.asign(newPlayer)
    newPlayer.move(data.x, data.y)
    console.log('drawing to canvas....')
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d')
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width * tileSize, height * tileSize)
    context.draw(context)
}

export default ReactRogue
```

Player.js

```
class Player {
    constructor(x, y, tilesize) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.tilesize = tilesize;

        move(dx, dy) {
            this.x += dx;
            this.dy += dy;
        }

        draw(context) {
            context.fillStyle = "#f00";
            context.textBaseline = "Hanging";
            context.font = "16px Helevetica";
            context.fillText('@', this.x * this.tilesize, this.y * this.tilesize);
        }
    }
}

export default Player
```

Any help would be be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dawson

Comment: Close your constructor with `}`

Comment: You have asked many questions without accepting answers. Make sure to go back through your questions and click the empty check mark next to the answer that helped you, to help others find the answer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

why are you defining functions in the constructor? Put it outside the constructor, in the class, and use arrow functions, like so:

```
class Player {
// constructor
  move = (dx, dy) => {
    this.x += dx;
    this.dy += dy;
  }

  draw = context => {
    context.fillStyle = "#f00";
    context.textBaseline = "Hanging";
    context.font = "16px Helevetica";
    context.fillText('@', this.x * this.tilesize, this.y * this.tilesize);
  }
}
```

and in ReactRogue, each line does not have a semicolon:

```
// you put ReactRougue
const ReactRogue = ({ width, height, tileSize }) => {
// useRef what?
    const canvasRef = useRef();
    const [player, setPlayer] = useState(new Player(1, 2, tileSize));
    let InputManager = new InputManager();
// is this a function? if so, then you have to put
// const handleInput = (action, data) => {function goes here}
    const handleInput = (action, data);
    let newPlayer = new Player();
// you put object.asign()
    object.assign(newPlayer);
    newPlayer.move(data.x, data.y);
    console.log('drawing to canvas....');
    const context = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width * tileSize, height * tileSize);
    context.draw(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As JS-Skipper suggested I refactored my code and move things out of constructors and everything starched working fine. Thanks for the help.

Dawson